# Looping over Json Array In JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am calling from an API to get the response in json format. I would like to loop through that response and only get the data once as it brings up results twice.

```
var url = "api call";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

 
xhr.send();
```

Response in json I get is:

```
{
    "next": "url",
    "data": [
        {
            "profile_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000012f44",
            "value": {
                "signal": 0.61,
                "connection": "radio_low_power",
                "profile_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000013ee4"
            },
            "timestamp": "2022-07-22T14:52:37.359000Z",
            "type": "seen_device"
        },
        {
            "profile_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000012f44",
            "value": 0.61,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-22T14:52:37.359000Z",
            "type": "connection_signal"
        },
        {
            "profile_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000012f44",
            "value": {
                "signal": 0.58,
                "connection": "radio_low_power",
                "profile_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000013ee4"
            },
            "timestamp": "2022-07-22T14:37:32.096000Z",
            "type": "seen_device"
        },
...]}
```

I would like to loop and show only the type:"seen_device", value, timestamp.

This is what i've tried so far to loop the data:

```
for(let i = 0; i < xhr.length; i++) {
          let obj = xhr.responseText[i];
           console.log("hello");
          console.log(xhr.responseText.data);
      }
   }};
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code being used to do the loop

Comment: _"i don't seem to be getting the response at all"_ - Then you should first fix that problem before you ask about a topic that will only work when the response problem is fixed...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Why do you think this is a dupe? There are only some logs in the `onreadystatechange` handler and no `return` or `... = xhr.send()`.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Why do you think this is a dupe?

Comment: @Andreas usually questions asking why the response is undefined are trying to use the data before it's available

Comment: @evolutionxbox Which is obviously not the case here.

Answer (score -1):

Because you looping async data, means you are trying to loop when data is not present, you need to add check if the response is not undefined and data on which you want to loop should have length

```
putting a sample code

function loopOverDat(){
 response && response.length && response.forEach(item => .....);
}
```

Comment: _"Because you looping async data, means you are trying to loop when data is not present..."_ - There's no loop in OPs question. And most importantly: _"...I don't seem to be getting the response at all"_

Comment: Sorry let me apologise i get the response in json always from the api but what i meant is that when i try to loop the data and get the response from the loop data i am not getting it.